# Forbidden permission to access /cgi-bin/test.pl

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

Okay so I have configured Apache on my Linux machine but when I try to run any sort of script on local host from the cgi-bin I get Forbidden permission. i.e. address http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.pl

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    <Files ~ "\.(pl|cgi)$">
        SetHandler perl-script
        PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
        Options +ExecCGI
        PerlSendHeader On
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

That is my 000-default.conf
And yes I have given test.pl 755 permissions and it does run correctly.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What are the permissions on the `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` directory?  Are you able to run other cgi scripts from that directory?

Comment: Off-topic. This question belongs on http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: @ikegami There's a bit of gray area, but the [consensus on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261726/176646) is that webserver configuration questions are on-topic here (some questions are *also* on-topic on SF and/or SU, but that doesn't make them off-topic here).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Reread your link. The consensus is that this can be in the realm of end-users, so it might not belong on SF. I 100% agree, which is why I think this question belongs on http://superuser.com/, and that it's can also be acceptable on http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: The permissions of the /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ directory is drwxr-xr-x. I cant run any other scripts from the directory.

Answer (score 0):

do "ls" on each of level.. /usr/ ,  /usr/lib/ , /usr/lib/cgi-bin without sudo... probably the owner of that file is 'root', if so.. then try 'chown' that file.

Comment: I can "ls" on each level so I assume they all have the right permissions.